Filter CSV rows where specific fields are null or non-null
I'm trying to filter lines in a CSV file based on two specific conditions, using awk:

Field 2 should be null (empty) and Field 4 should be non-null (not empty).
Field 2 should be non-null (not empty) and Field 4 should be null (empty).

For example, consider a CSV file with the following content:
"venBio","http://www.venbio.com","","venBio is a Investor located in United States, North America."
"zhenZhou","http://www.zhenzhou.com","",""
"Loren","","","A famous Hollywood actress from the 1950s and 1960s"

I want the awk script to first print:
"Loren","","","A famous Hollywood actress from the 1950s and 1960s"

followed by
"zhenZhou","http://www.zhenzhou.com","",""

I've tried various approaches, but I can't seem to get the filtering right for these conditions. Could someone guide me on the proper awk syntax to achieve this?

Approaches tried:
awk -F, '($2 == "" && $4 != "")' input.csv

awk -F, '($2 != "" && $4 == "")' input.csv

awk -F, '($2 ~ /^[[:space:]]*$/ && $4 !~ /^[[:space:]]*$/)' input.csv

awk -F, '($2 !~ /^[[:space:]]*$/ && $4 ~ /^[[:space:]]*$/)' input.csv


please share the command you have tried

are all fields guaranteed to be wrapped in double quotes? can any of the fields contain embedded double quotes?

You say "I've tried various approaches", so show us something you've tried so we have something to start from.

in the case of your sample data the use of -F, means the double quotes are treated as part of the field values so $2 == "" would need to be rewritten $2 == "\"\""; you'll also run into problems using -F, when one of your fields includes an embedded comma, eg, 1st line, last field contains a comma between United States and North America, in which case your script will actually treat the last field as 2 separate fields "venBio is a Investor located in United States and North America."

If this is really a general CSV file, awk won't be of much help. Imagine a multi-line field where the first character after the opening double quote is a newline character. Since awk is line oriented, it won't understand that this field crosses line boundaries.

@user1934428 awk is record-oriented, it only treats each line as a record by default, but you can have multi-line records too. See whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk.

@EdMorton : You are right, but this does not help you in our case, because you won't find a suitable record separator for awk. What I do find interesting, ist the --csv option mentioned in your linked to. Of course, reading enough of data into awk so that you can decompose it manually into pieces, can be done, since awk is just a general programming language. However, it effectively means that you are implementing a CSV parser in awk. I don't think that the OP had this in mind. For me, the preferable way would be to use a language which already comes with a parser (Ruby, Perl,...)

You may use this awk:
awk -F, -v nul='""' '$2 != nul && $4 == nul {s = s $0 ORS}
$2 == nul && $4 != nul; END {printf "%s", s}' file

"Loren","","","A famous Hollywood actress from the 1950s and 1960s"
"zhenZhou","http://www.zhenzhou.com","",""


Brilliant! Congrats on surpassing the 780,000 mark!

note that this breaks on more realistic csv. for example: "Fairbanks, Jr.","","notempty","","notempty"

For that we can use gnu-awk awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"' -v nul='""' '$2 != nul && $4 == nul {s = s $0 ORS} $2 == nul && $4 != nul; END {printf "%s", s}' file however there can be some cases where that will also break and we will need a proper CSV parser for those special cases.

The One True Awk supports CSV directly but XOR still has to be implemented as NOT/AND/OR:
awk --csv '(!length($2)&&length($4)) || (length($2)&&!length($4))' input.csv

giving:
"zhenZhou","http://www.zhenzhou.com","",""
"Loren","","","A famous Hollywood actress from the 1950s and 1960s"

If you really want the output in the order from the question, you can run the command twice:
awk --csv '!length($2)&&length($4)' input.csv
awk --csv 'length($2)&&!length($4)' input.csv

giving:
"Loren","","","A famous Hollywood actress from the 1950s and 1960s"
"zhenZhou","http://www.zhenzhou.com","",""


Assumptions:

all fields are wrapped in double quotes
no fields include embedded/escaped double quotes

If we use -F'"' to designate the input field delimiter then we just need to remember that all data fields are actually even-numbered (ie, 1st field is referenced as $2, 2nd field is referenced as $4).
Modifying and combining OP's 1st two awk scripts:
awk -F'"' '
FNR==NR { if ($4 == "" && $8 != "") print; next }    # process 1st file
        { if ($4 != "" && $8 == "") print       }    # process 2nd file
' input.csv input.csv

NOTES:

$4 is the 2nd data field; $8 is the 4th data field
print with no args is treated the same as print $0 (ie, print the entire line as is)
we provide two references of the input file (input.csv) in order to limit memory usage while generating the output in the desired order

This generates:
"Loren","","","A famous Hollywood actress from the 1950s and 1960s"
"zhenZhou","http://www.zhenzhou.com","",""


By setting -F, you inform GNU AWK that , is field separator but not that fields are encased in ", thus empty field is seen as "" (string of length 2 consisting of 2 double-quotes). If you have or are you allowed to install new enough GNU AWK version you might use --csv option as shown in Working With Comma Separated Value Files chapter of User Manual, otherwise just you might determine if field is empty using field, let file.csv content be
"venBio","http://www.venbio.com","","venBio is a Investor located in United States, North America."
"zhenZhou","http://www.zhenzhou.com","",""
"Loren","","","A famous Hollywood actress from the 1950s and 1960s"

then
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}(length($2)==2)+(length($4)==2)==1' file.csv

gives output
"zhenZhou","http://www.zhenzhou.com","",""
"Loren","","","A famous Hollywood actress from the 1950s and 1960s"

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that , is field separator (FS) then I filter lines where length of 2nd field is 2 xor length of 4th field is 2. I implement XOR by summing two conditions, which will give 1 if and only if exactly one holds true.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

The problem with the commands you tried is that awk is not ignoring the double quotes within each field. You can use the separator argument to solve that:
awk -F'","' '($2 == "" && $4 != "\"") || ($2 != "" && $4 == "\"")' file.csv

Because field $4 is the last one, you still need to account for that last double quote.

If you want to use a true csv parser (other than on GNU awk) you can use Ruby:
ruby -r csv -ne 'BEGIN{a=[]}
li=CSV.parse_line($_); a.unshift($_) if li[1].empty? ^ li[3].empty?
END{puts a.join }' f.csv

Prints:
"Loren","","","A famous Hollywood actress from the 1950s and 1960s"
"zhenZhou","http://www.zhenzhou.com","",""


IIUC, for the latest GNU awk 5.3.0:
awk --csv '($2=="") != ($4=="")' input.csv
#"zhenZhou","http://www.zhenzhou.com","",""
#"Loren","","","A famous Hollywood actress from the 1950s and 1960s"

note: this one only works when the order does not matter.
To make the desired order, another two-pass solution can be:
awk --csv '($(2+n) == "") && ($(4-n) != "")' input.csv n=2 input.csv 
#"Loren","","","A famous Hollywood actress from the 1950s and 1960s"
#"zhenZhou","http://www.zhenzhou.com","",""

so with the first pass, n="", we test against ($(2+0),$(4-0)) or ($2,$4), for the second pass n=2 and we test ($(2+2), $(4-2) which is ($4,$2).
note2: For more general cases, the above n is the difference between two concerned column numbers, for example if you want to test against $1 and $5, then n=4(which is 5-1), the command line will be: awk --csv '($(1+n) == "") && ($(5-n) != "")' input.csv n=4 input.csv
For GNU awk 4.0.0+, using FPAT to parse CSV file, the above awk command lines can be adjusted to (below consider two consecutive double-quotes as the only EMPTY CSV field parsed by FPAT):
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*' -v q='""' '($2 == q) != ($4 == q)' input.csv
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*' -v q='""' '($(2+n) == q) && ($(4-n) != q)' input.csv n=2 input.csv

In a more general CSV file parsed by FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*', NULL fields can be either empty string or two consecutive double quotes (for example ($2 == "" || $2 == q), or using regexp $2 ~ /^(""|)$/), so the above logic conditions can be improved to the following(remove the option -v q='""' from the command line):
($2 ~ /^(""|)$/) != ($4 ~ /^(""|)$/)
($(2+n) ~ /^(""|)$/) && ($(4-n) !~ /^(""|)$/)

For GNU awk 4.2.0+ which supports regexp constant, the above code can be more efficient and readable:
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*' -v nul='@/^(""|)$/' '($2 ~ nul) != ($4 ~ nul)' input.csv
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*' -v nul='@/^(""|)$/' '($(2+n) ~ nul) && ($(4-n) !~ nul)' input.csv n=2 input.csv


What you can try to use awk syntax to achieve your requirement:
#!/bin/bash

filename="data.csv"

awk -F',' '($2 == "" && $4 != "")' "$filename"
awk -F',' '($2 != "" && $4 == "")' "$filename"

